# scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(): exactly what does truncate_mode='level' do?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) says, "No more than `p` levels of the dendrogram tree are displayed. A “level” includes all nodes with `p` merges from the last merge." (`p` is another parameter) I can't figure out what "`p` merges from the last merge" means. Can anyone explain it?

(I've created dendrograms of the same data with `truncate_mode='level'` and `truncate_mode='lastp'`; I didn't find the comparison illuminating.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code demonstrates `truncate_mode='level'` and `truncate_mode='lastp'`:

```py
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1729)
ytdist = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 36)

Z = hierarchy.linkage(ytdist, 'single')
fig, ax_rows = plt.subplots(ncols=6, nrows=2, sharey=True, figsize=(16, 5))

for ax_row, truncate_mode in zip(ax_rows, ['level', 'lastp']):
    hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, ax=ax_row[0])
    ax_row[0].set_title('default, no truncation')
    for ind, ax in enumerate(ax_row[1:]):
        if truncate_mode == 'level':
            p = len(ax_row) - ind - 1
        else:
            p = len(ax_row) - ind
        hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, truncate_mode=truncate_mode, p=p, ax=ax)
        ax.set_title(f"truncate_mode='{truncate_mode}', p={p}")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparison plot]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! (It would be incrementally more helpful if the order of truncations was reversed for the subplots so the least severe truncation was next to the untruncated results.) And to go from the example to an answer to my question: The "last" merge referred to in the docs is the final merge, after which there is only one cluster containing all data. I was reading "last" as "previous."

Comment: FYI, I created a doc change pull request, which has been merged into scipy:master - https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/e53f57783989a6311b9ec50242010569e1bde2a1

Comment: I don't quite understand the chart truncate_mode='level', p=2. It seems that the small yellow split is 3 level from the final split, but it isn't truncated?